# Session data working in test server but not in live server (PHP)

Tags: php, session

The code works fine on localhost but not on live server.
There is no error, it can read and write to DB

The different is in data saved to DB

On localhost, saved data look like this:

```
SITE_LANG|s:2:"en";ClientID|s:2:"26";ClientGroupID|s:1:"1";
```

On live server, saved data look like this:

```
Np5e14FWKDVHzaaG-ZF_ynpH30c343pkf4b3w-fAOKJb6u9NZQtN8vTnBXxO3FtcKfQQE7JKq ...
```

The live server is dedicated server and we have other websites used session and all are working fine.
Please help :)

Comment: Looks like some sort of encryption or (assuming file based storage) mismatch in file encoding. I have had a weird issue where session files where stored in an alien encoding.

Comment: I use session_encode() and its working :) but why there is no need for this function in localhost and in other live sites? When we have to use session_encode()?

Comment: I may be too obvious, but do you decode it again on each request? If the answer is yes, I am out of clever ideas, sorry

Comment: Yes, I use session_decode in each page load -- [I found similar behavior](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php#89564)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this issue, just add this to .htaccess file:

```
php_flag "suhosin.session.encrypt" 0
php_flag "suhosin.cookie.encrypt" 0
```